# c++ pass pointer as parameter. How to understand it?

Tags: c++

I think the `printList` function in the followig snippet receives pointer as parameter. As a result, it will modify the `head` pointer. But actually, it's not. Otherwise, the second `printList` function cannot print the nodes at all, because the `head` pointer has move to `NULL` in first `printList` function.

```
ListNode * head = new ListNode(-1);
push(head, 5);
push(head, 20);
push(head, 4);
push(head, 3);
push(head, 30);
printf("%x", head);
printList(head);
printf("%x", head);

void printList(ListNode  *head) {
    while (head != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", head->val);
        head = head->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: You're passing a pointer which gets modified inside the function, but the content of it is not. Try with `ListNode*& head` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ has pass by value semantics.`head = head->next;` has no effect on the caller side, because `head` is local to the `printList` function. In this sense, passing a pointer is no different to passing an `int` or a `double`. You get a local copy of the passed object. The difference is that a pointer allows you to refer to a non-local object.

Answer (score 4):

The parameter `ListNode* head` takes a *copy* of a pointer. `head =` then only modifies that copy, and not the original pointer which was passed to the function.

If you need to modify the original pointer, pass a *reference* to it: `ListNode*& head`

Answer (score 3):

With this, you get a copy from the pointer.
If you want to modify the pointer itself you can write something like this.

```
void printlist(ListNode*& head)
```

The point of getting the pointer is to avoid copying the object itself, and you get it by pointer instead of reference when the value can be nullptr.